# OCaml - Wrong function type

Tags: oop, types, functional-programming, ocaml

I have made a class method, and I'd like to have this type :

`unit -> (dir -> 'b)`

But my actual method:

```
method iter () = fun x -> match x with
| Up -> if (Stack.is_empty pz) then raise Stack.Empty else if (Stack.length pz = 1) then failwith "Cannot go up" else (ignore (Stack.pop pz) ; {< a = (Stack.top pz) >})
| Down(v) -> match (Stack.top pz) with
| Noeud(o, {contents = []}) -> raise Not_found
| Noeud(o, {contents = l}) -> if mem_assoc v l then ((Stack.push (assoc v l) pz) ; {< a = (Stack.top pz) >} ) else raise Not_found
```

has the type `unit -> dir -> 'b`

How can I make it so it becomes the first type?

Here are the custom types :

```
    type 'a arbre =  Noeud of 'a option ref * (char * 'a arbre) list ref
    type dir = Up | Down of char
```

Edit: I need this so it can comply to a certain interface, and because of the type mismatch, it won't compile.
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the problem. `unit -> (dir -> 'b)` and `unit -> dir -> 'b` are the same type in OCaml! (the type arrow is right-associative)

Could you show us the actual error message so we can know where the problem lies?

Addendum: have you actually tried this? If there *is* no other issue, then you'll find it'll just work.

Comment: actually, I have no error message, it now compiles fine. But when I run my code in some pre-written tests, in won't find other funtions... If I try modifying the interface for this method only, it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "pre-written tests" or "won't find other functions". Again, real error messages and examples will help. :)

Comment: After all it was working, just a type in the interface name. Thanks for your help though.